# Do bearded faces age slower?

Tags: dermatology, aging, sun-exposure, uv-rays, facial-hair

[Recent research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3790843/) indicates that UV exposure may be responsible for around 80% of facial skin aging symptoms. The more unprotected exposure from the sun, the more the skin ages.

Does the evidence show that chronically bearded men, who have part of their face protected from sun exposure for years or decades, show less facial skin aging symptoms in these areas?

Comment: how would you know unless you remove the beard?  And if they're wearing it for religious reasons you can't remove the beard.